# Select2 overwrites knockout observableArray with string

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 with a custom knockout binding to provide dynamic tagging support. Unfortunately when the select2 control is modified by the user, the bound observable array is overwritten with a comma separated value string instead of simply adding the new value to the observable array. I'm guessing this has to do with the way I'm binding the input value, but I can't seem to find an alternative approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gk8a6sht/6/

JavaScript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
     var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()) || {};
     setTimeout(function() { 
         $(element).select2(options);
     }, 0);
   }
};    

var viewModel = {
    values: ko.observableArray(["red", "grey", "blue"])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Html:

```
<input data-bind="value: values, select2: { tags: values, tokenSeparators: [',', ' '] }"/>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, looks much better now. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Have you checked the answer? If it helped, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

Corrected `split` function in the code below to use specified `tokenSeparators`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk8a6sht/10/) is also updated.

**Edit:**

I've read a little about [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin and its Tagging support. As I understood it, you've mixed up predefined set of tags (that is set in options) with actual tags, that are selected by user. I've significantly updated my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk8a6sht/10/), now the binding handler looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    defaults: {
        value: ko.observable(),
        select2Options: {
            tags: ko.observableArray([]),
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
        }
    },
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var bindingOptions = valueAccessor() || {},
            options =  $.extend(true, {},
                ko.bindingHandlers.select2.defaults,          
                bindingOptions),
            value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.value);
        $(element).val(value);
        $(element).select2(ko.toJS(options.select2Options));
        $(element).change(function() {
            options.value($(element).val().split(options.select2Options.tokenSeparators));
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(valueAccessor().value());
    }
};
```

First of all, I've added defaults for convenience, so you don't have to specify token separators each time, for example. Next, I've moved all the plumbing for tags selection to binding handler, now your view model looks like this:

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.predefinedValues= ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedValues = ko.observableArray();
};
ViewModel.prototype.init = function() {
    // Here we should init our model with values from server, for example
    this.predefinedValues(["red", "grey", "blue"]);
    this.selectedValues(["red"]);
}
```

So now you have 2 observable arrays - first is predefined set of tags, second is actual array of selected tags.

Markup looks as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" style="width: 300px" data-bind="select2: { value: selectedValues, select2Options: { tags: predefinedValues }}"/>
```

So there are no strings anymore, everything is done inside binding handler.

**Original answer:**

Just use another observable to keep the value of select2 string, like this:

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: selectedValuesString, select2: { tags: values, tokenSeparators: [',', ' '] }"/>
```

Javascipt:

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.values= ko.observableArray(["red", "grey", "blue"]);
    self.selectedValuesString= ko.observable(self.values().join(","));
    self.selectedValuesString.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.values(newValue.split(','));
    });
};
```

I've changed view model declaration from object to function so it would be easier to write a subscribing function.

Also you should use `update` function in your custom binding to react on list changes.

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk8a6sht/8/) to show how it works. I've added `Add value` button to see how it would work with adding elements. And I used a random number to add to new values, since select2 doesn't like similar values I guess (treats them like one value).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply and solution. This approach certainly works with the provided token separators. The downside of relying on the 'split' function is that it fails if you allow commas in your tags (remove the ',' from from the tokenSeparators array to see). This is more an issue of how select2 updates the input, and you could likely overcome this with some clever JavaScript.

Comment: @mindlessgoods, oops, I've simply overlooked that. See edited answer, I've updated [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gk8a6sht/10/). I guess now it deserves a vote up ;)